# Welche grammatische Form kann das erste Wort in zusammengesetzen Wörtern annehmen?

Tags: grammatical-number, compound, genitive

Im Deutschen kann der erste Teil eines zusammengesetzten Wortes in der "Einzahl" oder "Mehrzahl" mit und ohne "Fugen-s" angefügt werden:

> Haarbürste, Haaresbreite, Kindskopf, Kindeskind

Hier fällt schon auf, dass nicht einfach ein 's' angefügt wird und dass es nicht so ist, dass es für bestimmte Wörter festgelegt ist, ob man '-s' oder '-es' verwendet.

Es gibt auch regionale Unterschiede:

> Adventskranz, Adventkranz (öst.)

Bildungen, die wie Plural aussehen:

> Sonnenschein, Fliegenpilz

Auch zwischen den beiden Gruppen gibt es regionale und historische Varianten:

> Mondschein, Mondenschein (alt/poetisch)
>   Schweinebraten, Schweinsbraten (öst.)

Manche Formen sprechen klar dagegen, dass es sich um einen Plural handelt:

> Märzenbecher (gelbe Narzisse)

Nun zur Frage:

Handelt es sich bei diesen Formen ursprünglich um Nominativ/Genitiv/Plural, die mit dem Sinn des Wortes etwas zu tun haben, oder um eine reine Fugenbildung, die die Aussprache erleichtern soll, oder ist es gemischt?

Comment: Hier findet man übrigens eine Landkarte, die die Regionale Verwendung von Schweinebraten und Schweinsbraten aufzeigt: http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_3/f01a-d/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Haarbürste, Haaresbreite, Kindskopf, Kindeskind
>
> Haar-Bürste, des Haares Breite, Kind-Kopf, des Kindes Kind

Hier würde ich mutmaßen, dass es sich um zwei Genitive und zwei Zusammensetzungen handelt, von denen die zweite ein Fugen-S bekommen hat, um sich besser aussprechen zu lassen. Beim Kindskopf könnte man sich natürlich ebenfalls den Genitiv vorstellen, aber da es sich nicht um den Kopf eines Kindes handelt, sondern um einen kindischen Kopf, passt hier sicher die Zusammensetzung besser, während das Kind des Kindes wörtlich zu verstehen ist. Der Grimm bestätigt meine diesbezügliche Annahme:

> 2) persönlich, wie dummkopf, dickkopf, trotzkopf, kalbskopf u. a. von einem kindischen menschen Schmeller 2, 309, besonders um eigensinn, trotz, wankelmut, auch albernheit zu bezeichnen, kindskopf dummkopf

Die Haarbürste andererseits ist ja *für* Haare, während es sich bei der Haaresbreite um die Breite *eines* Haares handelt. Das ist jetzt hoffentlich nicht zu haarspalterisch.

Der [Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,293195,00.html) gibt einen Überblick über die Verwendung des Fugen-S, räumt aber ein, dass es keine einheitlichen Regeln gibt. Auch findet sich hier ein amüsanter Artikel über [Bratskartoffeln und Spiegelsei](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,293186,00.html).

Generell gilt für Fugenlaute, dass sie regional unterschiedlich eingesetzt und im Amtsdeutsch gewöhnlich weggelassen werden. Sie dienen nur der flüssigeren Aussprache. Aus dem Genitiv hergeleitete Einschübe sind meines Wissens keine Fugenlaute, sondern ähneln ihnen.

Dann gibt es noch die Pluralendungen. Wikipedia hat hierzu folgendes:

> Durch Übereinstimmungen mit den Pluralsuffixen wird man häufig dazu verleitet, zu glauben, dass die Fugenelemente aus ihnen entsprungen seien. Diese Annahme ist allerdings falsch, denn die althochdeutschen Fugenelemente sind stets die Stammbildungssuffixe der jeweiligen Flexionsklasse. Das bedeutet, dass sie der a-, i-, ir- und n-Klasse angehören und sich dann zu den Interfixen -e (← -a und -i), -er (← -ir) und -(e)n entwickelt haben, zum Beispiel Althochdeutsch geburtitag → Neuhochdeutsch Geburtstag. Genau dieselben Stammbildungssuffixe wurden später zu Pluralsuffixen umfunktioniert.

Anderswo liest sich:

> Im Fall von Sonnenschein ist es übringens [sic!] so, dass es sich hierbei um ein (veraltetes) sog. pränominales Genitivattribut handelt und tatsächlich nicht um ein Pluralflexiv. Wir kennen dieses Flexiv halt nicht mehr, deshalb erscheint die Bildung uns unlogisch.

Bei vielen dieser vermeintlichen Pluralbildungen handelt es sich auch um Dinge, die es nur einmal gibt. Das gilt zumindest für deine Beispiele Sonne, Mond und März. Der Schweinebraten scheint ja eher ein Fugenlaut der Aussprache wegen zu sein.

---

Der Wikipedia-Artikel zum Fugenlaut erwähnt noch einige Beispiele für die Bildung von Wörtern (unabhängig vom Fugenlaut). Bei diesen Zusammensetzungen kann sich das Vorderwort verändern, darunter in die Mehrzahl oder in die Genitivform. Das Fugen-S erscheint andererseits häufig auch bei Wörtern, die im Genitiv gar nicht auf S enden. Der Vollständigkeit halber, passend zur eigentlichen Frage bzw. deren Überschrift, die Liste der möglichen Formen des Vorderworts aus dem Artikel:

- Stammform: Kronprinz, Seelsorger
- Vollständige Einzahl: Haustür, Gasthaus
- Vollständige Mehrzahl: Kartenhaus, Gänsebraten
- Genitiv: Bundesbank, Verbandskasten

Dann gibt es noch Sonderfälle:

- Genitivform: keinesfalls, nötigenfalls
- Veränderte Genitivform: meinetwegen, deinetwegen (keine Regel herleitbar!)
- Reiner Fugenlaut: eigentlich, hoffentlich, morgendlich (!)

> Das Fugen-s, auch Binde-s genannt, ist der häufigste Fugenlaut und gleicht oft der Genitivform des Vorderworts. Es erscheint jedoch auch bei Wörtern, die gar kein Genitiv-s kennen: Hochzeitskleid, Liebeslied, Abfahrtszeit usw.

Comment: Holla, die Waldfee. Soviel wollte ich gar nicht schreiben. Hoffentlich ist das jetzt nicht zuviel geworden ;)

Comment: +1 Das nennt sich erschöpfende Behandlung des Themas :)

Comment: Ja, genau, erschöpfend im Sinne von tl;dr  ;-)

Comment: Ist dieser amüsante Ausdruck "Holla, die Waldfee"  deine Erfindung, OregonGhost, oder ein üblicher Ausruf?

Comment: @jae: Ach komm, manche Fragen haben eben komplizierte Antworten ;)

Comment: @Georges: nicht Oregon's Erfindung, ich habe den Ausdruck auch schon gehört und selbst benutzt.

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg: Nein, meine Erfindung ist das nicht, das ist wohl ein *relativ* üblicher Ausruf des Erstaunens. Der Grimm schweigt sich dazu leider aus. [Gerüchten zufolge](http://www.sheng-fui.de/aktuell/raetsel-um-redewendung-holla-die-waldfee-endgueltig-geklaert/) handelt es sich um ein Märchen aus dem Nachlass von Charlotte Grimm, die ihren berühmten Brüdern zeitlebens vorwarf, die Märchen zu entstellen... Aber wer weiß das schon :) Ich habe ihn glaube ich in der siebten Klasse erstmalig von einer älteren Deutschlehrerin gehört.

Comment: Danke, OregonGhost. In jedem Fall gefällt mir der Ausdruck sehr: ich werde mal versuchen, ihn in einem Gespräch lässig zu benutzen...

Comment: @Oregon: "ältere Deutschlehrerin"... ah, könnte meine Generation gewesen sein. ;-)  @Georges: der Spruch ist mit ziemlicher Sicherheit nicht so alt, wie der von OregonGhost verlinkte Artikel (der pure Satire ist) glauben machen will.  Ist aus den 70ern/80ern.  WIMNI, of course.

Comment: @jae: Sie war schon damals (vor gut 15 Jahren) schon an die 60.

Answer (score 0):

Laut Duden wird das Fugen-s bei bestimmten Endungen der ersten Wortkomponente verwendet:  -tum, -ing, -ling, -heit, -keit, -schaft, -ung, -ion, -tät, -at oder -um. Beispiele sind Mannschaftswettbewerb, Bewerbungstraining, Heiterkeitsausbruch, Religionswissenschaft, Wissenschaftsrat, Forschungserfolg, Irrtumswahrscheinlichkeit.

Link: [Dudeneintrag Komposita](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/komposita-mit-fruehling-und-fruehjahr)