# How to make German compound noun?

Tags: compound

In the German language the compound noun always consists of more than one lexeme. There is an *s* between some of them, take *Arbeitsgruppe* as an example, while others don't have it, like *Waldblume*. 
I just want to know on which condition should I add *s* and when not?

Comment: Technically speaking, a compound is a word and it sounds a bit weird to me saying that a word consist of more than one word. That's why I changed it in my edit to lexeme.

Comment: also related but in German: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5253/fugenkonsonanten-bei-zusammengesetzten-wörtern

Comment: also in German: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/942/welche-grammatische-form-kann-das-erste-wort-in-zusammengesetzen-wörtern-annehme

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/16121/guidelines-for-the-formation-of-compound-nouns

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule. Even native speakers of German are not always in agreement, depending on region (Austrians vs. German, e.g.)